# holy: santo vs. sagrado

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, religión, vocabulario

What is the difference between *santo* and *sagrado* in translating the English religious word "holy." How are the two words used in religious contexts in Spanish-speaking countries?

Comment: As far as I can tell holy=santo/a sacred=sagrado

Comment: Is there a question here that can't be answered by reading the dictionary definitions of [santo](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=santo) and [sagrado](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=sagrado)?

Comment: @Flimzy: My dictionary lists "holy" as a translation for both words. I'm trying to figure out when you'd use which when translating "holy" from English.

Comment: A translation dictionary probably is not sufficient in this case.  I liked to the RAE definitions (in Spanish) of both words above. The definitions there are much more in-depth than a translation dictionary can provide. Let me know if those help answer your question.

Comment: @Flimzy: Those do help clarify some. It sounds though from Janoma's answer that there's no easy rule... some set phrases (like Holy Family) probably just need to be memorized.

Comment: Just extrapolate the meanings that are in sagrado and not in santo and that's it. I agree with Flimzy. RAE is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holy means *sagrado* and *santo* in the sense of *sacred*:

> Holy Land : Tierra santa
>
> Holy Spirit : Espíritu santo
>
> Holy Bible : la santa biblia (common) *or* la sagrada biblia (uncommon)
>
> Holy Family : la sagrada familia (as in [Gaudí's masterpiece](http://www.sagradafamilia.cat/sf-eng/?lang=0))
>
> Holy Grial : el santo grial

It's also translated as *bendito(a)*:

> Holy water : agua bendita

However, *santo* is the word used for a saint:

> Saint Patrick : San Patricio. Patricio es un santo.
>
> Saint Mary : Santa María. María es una santa.
>
> All Saints' Day : día de todos los santos.